# Formatting my date time

Tags: powershell

When I run the following code it outputs the information I want, but im having trouble with the final out put. It shows my UpTime as days,hours,minutes,seconds. I would just like Days and hours. And I would like to move the Uptime to display last on my list. The out put right now is Uptime, Computer, LastBootupTime.

```
Function Get-UpTime 
{ Param ([string[]]$servers) 
   Foreach ($s in $servers)  
   {  
     $os = Get-WmiObject -class win32_OperatingSystem -cn $s -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue  
     New-Object psobject -Property @{computer=$s; 
     LastBootUpTime = [Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]::ToDateTime( (Get-WmiObject - Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Computer $s | Select -Exp LastBootUpTime) )
     UpTime = (Get-Date) – [System.Management.ManagementDateTimeconverter]::ToDateTime((Get-WmiObject - Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Computer $s | Select -Exp LastBootUpTime)) 
   }
}}
Get-UpTime -servers $servers| 
ConvertTo-Html -As Table -body " 
<h1>Server Uptime Report</h1> 
The following report was run on $(get-date)" >> $path  
Invoke-Item $path
```

Comment: So output the first two lines to the file, and then run your `Get-Uptime` and pipe it to `ConvertTo-Html -As Table -Properties Uptime, Computer, LastBootupTime` specifying the properties, and the order you want them in.

Answer (score 0):

Next code snippet gives desired output: shows `UpTime` as `days.hours:minutes` last on the list; moreover, displays all tested servers (shows `N/A` in place of `LastBootUpTime` and `UpTime` if an RPC server is unavailable).

```
Function Get-UpTime 
{   Param ([string[]]$servers) 
    Foreach ($s in $servers) {
        Try 
        {   $os = Get-WmiObject -class win32_OperatingSystem -cn $s
            $ST = [System.Management.ManagementDateTimeconverter]::
                       ToDateTime(($os | Select -Exp LastBootUpTime))
            $UT = (Get-Date) – $ST  # Days.Hours:Minutes:Seconds.MillisecondsFraction
                                    # e.g. 114.12:32:42.6025504
            New-Object psobject -Property @{
                Computer = $s
               #UpTime   = $UT.ToString().Substring(0, $UT.ToString().Length - 11)
                UpTime   = '' + $UT.Days + '.' + $UT.Hours + ':' + $UT.Minutes
                LastBootUpTime = $ST
            }
        } 
        Catch 
        {   New-Object psobject -Property @{
                Computer = $s
                UpTime   = "N/A"
                LastBootUpTime = "N/A"
            }
        }    
    }
}

Get-UpTime -servers $servers |
ConvertTo-Html -As Table -Property Computer, LastBootUpTime, UpTime -body " 
<h1>Server Uptime Report</h1> 
The following report was run on $(get-date)" >> $path
Invoke-Item $path
```